# Best WinForms Distribution Plan

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, distribution

I work in an metallurgic enterprise where we make our own productive software. We are considering change our distribution plan to fit our current needs. I was hoping you could give some ideas.

Our application is a WinForms, C# Framework 4.0. It's located in an intranet. It's divided in three projects (UX, Business layer and Model layer). The application is divided "logically" in modules where each one performs different tasks but they share some functionality (i.e. commercial module, financial module, quoting module).

It is required also that if its needed, log out all the users so they can update their application (in cases of a severe update).

We have two scenarios (maybe you could add others):

**Scenario 1.**

The whole application is only one EXE distributed with ClicOnce.

PROs:

- Easy to detect any change and how it affects.
- Just one distribution

CONs:

- Small changes affect the whole company (why update if the change does
  not affect my "module"?)
- Distribution heavier
- Must improve your testing so you left less bugs in distribution.

**Scenario 2.**

One small application (EXE) that "fires" different EXEs (one per module).

PROs:

- Updates lighters.
- Isolated errors.
- Isolated development.

CONs:

- Must detect each change in order to recompile/distribute each module
  (EXE) affected.
- Create a new project in order to store the shared stuff (forms,
  classes, etc).

What do you think? Do you know other distribution plans?

Thanks!

Javier

Comment: I know it is a bit off topic, but a lot of these concerns go away with an internet web application.  Why not got with this?  Technically, it is another type of distribution plan.

Comment: Perhaps, recoding an entire large application is a bit 'expensive'?

Comment: To me this looks like something for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have a scenario like the one above. We have solved with an internal webservice. Each workstation has a dedicated list of modules to be updated and asks the webservice if there is an update pending and then execute the update.

Comment: I don't know your budget, how many machines you need to configure, etc, but we use a single product for managing our remote locations including patching, software configuration...  http://www.convergentinfo.com/products/afaria_components/configuration.htm  Like you, we have certain locations/PCs with different versions of the same project depending on needs.  We have all installations stored on a server at the main corporate office, and divide retail locations into groups.  Scripts control which groups get which versions, etc. Not a fit for everyone, but kills many birds with one stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take the hybrid of your two scenarios and have a ClickOnce deployment per module.  Changes in the shared code would "trigger" a new deployment for each dependent module.

You can explore the [System.Deployment namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145029), particularly the [ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136935) for integrating the "severe update" requirement so that the application will update itself.

Comment: ClickOnce deployment will go quickly for minor updates since apparently only the modules that have changed need to be redeployed. I currently have a large, monolithic program deployed through ClickOnce and updates aren't that bad (or at least users haven't complained). Go with the hybrid solution as suggestion by Austin an you should be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I think someone already have had this problem.
He decided to create Dynamically linked libraries.

You should have

- 1 exe : the GUI with very simple code : only calls to modules
- n dll : the modules with a clear API to be called either by GUI or other modules.

Then you can easily replace one module with automatic updates.
That's how IE works for example.